# How to track events with Google analytics in the chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics-4

I'm using Google analytics in my extension for tracking click events. I want to use it in content_script file so I'm sending a message to the background with this code:

```
$('.auto-time-popup-span').click(function (e) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
   action: "quick_popup_event",
 });
})
```

and in the `background.js` I'm receiving message and track event like this code:

```
var _AnalyticsCode = 'UA-XXXXXXX-X';

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', _AnalyticsCode]);

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action == "quick_popup_event") {
      console.log("clicked")
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'quick-popup', 'clicked']);
}
 sendResponse();
});
```

I can print clicked in the console but I can't track the click event in the Google analytics. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can't send DOM elements via messages because these are different contexts.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ok! I've deleted DOM element and replaced it with a string. but it didn't work.